# How to determine why pandas dataframe missing last few lines

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This question might not be appropriate for this site but here goes:

I'm writing a csv file using:

```
writer.writerow(row)
```

It produces a file with 98329 lines. Then I read the file using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Now the dataframe has only 98266 lines.  It is missing the last 63 lines.  Maybe there's an EOF somewhere but I can't find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there any empty lines in the file? Are you positive it's the last 63 that are missing?

Comment: As far as Excel is concerned, there are no blank lines and I did verify that it is the last 63 lines which are missing.  It must be something about the way that pandas is reading the csv file.

Comment: But now I just rearranged the input file so that the last 200 or so lines are the first lines in the file and the result was the same.  Obviously, those same 63 lines aren't being read in.